# Insert Query to Oracle using Slick 2.1

Tags: oracle, scala, slick

I have faced really incomprehensible problem with insert query to oracle table by using Slick. And I don't know how to localize a mistake.

```
"com.typesafe.slick"      %%  "slick"                   % "2.1.0",
 "com.typesafe.slick"      %%  "slick-extensions"        % "2.1.0"
```

By inserting, I always get this exception:

```
[DEBUG] - from [scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement] in [pool-1-thread-1] - [Preparing insert statement: insert into "NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE" ("CLIENT_ID","IMPORTANCE","TYPE_ID","ACCOUNT","TITLE","MESSAGE","STATUS","CREATION_DATE")  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), returning: ID]
[ERROR] - from [mypackage.db.core.OracleDatabaseComponent] in [pool-1-thread-1] - [DB operation failed - error: [An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8]]
mypackage.db.core.DBProcessException: DB operation failed - error: [An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8]
```

But the most strange thing is that if I remove one parameter from the insert query(would be filled as default value), it would be executed with success. 
It's look like limit of the number of values in the Insert query, but there are no problems with another tables(some of them has more than 8 columns). 
Maybe somebody has met this problem or knows how to localize mistake ?

Table ddl:

```
create table NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE (
  id         number(20)                   not null,
  client_id          nvarchar2(32)                not null,
  importance         number(1)      default 1     not null,
  type_id            number(2)                    not null,
  account            nvarchar2(32),
  title              nvarchar2(255)               not null,
  message            nvarchar2(2000)              not null,
  status             nvarchar2(32)  default 'NEW' not null,
  creation_date      date       default sysdate   not null
)
```

Slick model:

```
import com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver.simple._   
case class NotificationMessage(
                                    id: Option[Long],
                                    clientId: String,
                                    importance: Int = 1,
                                    typeId: Int,
                                    account: Option[String],
                                    title: String,
                                    message: String,
                                    status: NotificationStatus,
                                    creationDate: Instant
                                    )
    class NotificationMessageTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[NotificationMessage](tag, "NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE") {

        def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        def clientId = column[String]("CLIENT_ID", O.NotNull)        
        def importance = column[Int]("IMPORTANCE", O.NotNull)        
        def typeId = column[Int]("TYPE_ID", O.NotNull)        
        def account = column[Option[String]]("ACCOUNT")        
        def title = column[String]("TITLE", O.NotNull)        
        def message = column[String]("MESSAGE", O.NotNull)        
        def status = column[NotificationStatus]("STATUS", O.NotNull)        
        def creationDate = column[Instant]("CREATION_DATE", O.NotNull)        
        override def * : ProvenShape[NotificationMessage] =
          (id.?, clientId, importance, typeId, account, title, message, status, creationDate) <>
            (NotificationMessage.tupled, NotificationMessage.unapply)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the id.?

just id. The column is not marked as optional.

as you can see, only 8 parameters are been used in the insert.

Comment: id should be optional for insert query, it would be defined in database by trigger. Also could you, please, explain the difference between column[Option[Long]] and using ".?" in def * ?

Comment: def id = column[Long]("ID", O.NotNull, O.PrimaryKey)
def * = (id, clientId, importance, typeId, account, title, message, status, creationDate) <>
            (NotificationMessage.tupled, NotificationMessage.unapply)

Comment: It wouldn't compile because Slick does not know how to map given types.